# MySQL: More rows, or more comma-delimited items in a single cell

Tags: mysql, database

Suppose a table called *diary* with 10 columns:

```
|id |date|cl2|cl3|cl4|cl5|cl6|cl7|cl8|activity|
|---|----|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|--------|
```

And a table called *activities*:

```
|activity_id|activity_name|
|-----------|-------------|
```

Activities table lists activities, like {id:1, name: Reading}, {id:2, name: Sports}, etc. The *dairy* table holds diary input, which could be one per day, several per day or one in several days. Each diary entry could be tagged with multiple activities.

Also suppose that table *diary* holds about 10 million entries and growing. About time to think about ways to optimise the DB.

The diary entries can be searched by any value, including by a tagged activity. I.e., it should be possible to look for diary entries, where activity_id *1* is tagged.

What would be the best structure in this environment, to enable the fastest writing, searching, editing and deleting of diary entries? Also, the DB size is an issue, albeit not an immediate issue. But should be weighed in when making the decision.

I have three options in my mind now:

1. For each activity tagged, add a new row, such as:

   ```
   |id |date  |diary_id|cl3|cl4|cl5|cl6|cl7|cl8|activity|
   |---|------|--------|---|---|---|---|---|---|--------|
   |1  |1-9-17|001     |xxx|xxx|xxx|xxx|xxx|xxx|1       |
   |2  |1-9-17|001     |xxx|xxx|xxx|xxx|xxx|xxx|2       |
   |3  |1-9-17|001     |xxx|xxx|xxx|xxx|xxx|xxx|5       |
   ```
2. Make a separate table for the tagged activities:

   `Table: *acitivity_tags*`

   ```
   |id |diary_id|activity_id|
   |---|--------|-----------|
   |1  |001     |1          |
   |2  |001     |2          |
   |3  |001     |5          |
   ```
3. Store the tagged activities as a comma delimited string and use `find_in_set` to look for the tagged activities:

   ```
   |id |date  |diary_id|cl3|cl4|cl5|cl6|cl7|cl8|activity|
   |---|------|--------|---|---|---|---|---|---|--------|
   |1  |1-9-17|001     |xxx|xxx|xxx|xxx|xxx|xxx|1,2,5   |
   ```

So, what is the most time and space efficient way of implementing this?

Comment: Option 3 is pretty bad because you are storing CSV data which is hard to query and manage.  I also don't like option 1 because the number of columns is fixed and maybe it might change later on.  This leaves Option 2 looking the best to me.

Comment: I reject the premise of the question. You wouldn't have a table with 10 columns

Comment: And why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer option 2 because it follows the rules of database normalization. In option 1 you're repeating all the data in the other columns, which is a waste of space. You'll have performance problems in option 3 because it won't be efficient to search a CSV field. If you have correct foreign keys and indexes on the foreign keys, then the performance of option 2 will be okay.